# static_cast call from curl to ordinary C++ function

Tags: c++, curl

EDITED:: To be more precise, it is how to do static_cast function calls that I don't understand. The line

```
static_cast<curlGet*>(up)->setData(dataInside);
```

is where the runtime error originates.
END EDIT

I've tried out using curl with c++, among other examples following this http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/45878/

Now I've would like to call it from a c++ object, and in turn output the reply to some other object. However, I get a runtime error, likely from when I call my write function, an error which I'm unable to resolve.
This should be the relevant FAQ
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Using_C_non_static_functions_f

My code is in two files, main.cpp and curlget.h. The main method begins with doing a "classic" call to get a webpage, after that it creates a getCurl object and calls the method makeGet() which is supposed to do the same GET operation again, but renders a runtime error.

I seem to be unable to find my mistake, and understanding how to properly do C stuff from a C++ object and then return information back to another C++ object. I've looked at other question regarding this but I feel to shaky on the C/C++ interaction.

After configuring location of curl.h and compiler commands for curl library the code should hopefully run by copy paste. I've skipped to do class implementation in a separate file to avoid clutter.

Here goes the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <include/curl/curl.h> //This must be changed according to local configuration
#include <curlget.h>

using namespace std;

string data;

size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{
    for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
{
    data.push_back(buf[c]);
}
return size*nmemb;
}

int main()
{
CURL* curl;
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

curl_easy_perform(curl);

cout << endl << data << endl;
cin.get();

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_global_cleanup();

cout<<"MIDDLE ========================"<<endl;

curlGet c;
c.makeGet();
return 0;
}
```

**curlget.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <include/curl/curl.h>

#ifndef CURLGET_H
#define CURLGET_H

class curlGet
{
public:
curlGet(){};

std::string data2;
std::string setData(std::string s){
    data2=s;
}

static size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{
    std::string dataInside;

    for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
    {
        dataInside.push_back(buf[c]);
    }
    static_cast<curlGet*>(up)->setData(dataInside); 
//The line above "causes" the problem, no runtime error if the line is commented


    return size*nmemb;
}

void makeGet(){
    CURL* curl;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlGet::writeCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    std::cout << std::endl << data2 << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

}
};

#endif // CURLGET_H
```

Comment: _'but renders a runtime error'_ Could you be a bit more precise about this please? Also inspecting your code with a debugger first might give you better and faster results than you can get here.

Comment: I've added a code comment. My question is more about how to do static_cast function calls properly